# php sql multiple queries. Is it a big deal?

Tags: php, sql, cart

I have a cart class, where I store the product ids. The user can open the cart through a button that opens the cart in a popup, so the cart content has to be loaded in every page.

I can store only the ids of the products because of the size limits, but I want to show the product names to the final user, so for each element I need to make a query and get the product data from the database.

Is there any major drawback by doing this? Or are there better solutions?

PS: I could get the id of all the products in the cart, and then do one single query that gets the data of any needed product. I’d rather avoid this since I would need to rewrite parts of the class, so is there any actual difference with the previous solution?

PPS: The total number of sql queries shouldn’t be too high in any case. Of course I wouldn’t mind, but I strongly doubt any user will purchase hundreds of different products at one time.

Comment: Sounds like you should be running one query to get the data for all relevant products at the beginning, and creating the product records based on that single query. One query for each product certainly shouldn't be necessary unless you have multi-dimensional data associated with the products, and even then there are ways to get it all in one query.

Comment: Do you really think that storing product names in a session are a memory issue? I doubt that … have you tested it?

Comment: where do you store the IDs if you have the memory issue? solution with 1 or 2 queries is fine, 1+n is not. There are many ways to solve this but we dont have enough info because it is hard to understand you.

Comment: of course doing extra SQL queries is not good and you should use one query, but how much traffic are you getting. Maybe it not a big deal if it is low traffic. But don't create a problem for the future.

Comment: You don't need to rewrite the cart class. You create a second one with `extends` and then only change the part that needs change BTW. Then when you find out that your first approach takes too long, you can easily replace it without changing much more else in your application. And then in the end if it even takes longer, you use the old class again. See: SRP - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: Also keep as guidline what is most wanted. You want users to buy as much as possible. So make that easy (which means *fast*) for users.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, you helped me to see more clearly through this. About the memory issue... Yes I have it when using cookies, the previous code was storing all the necessary data and didn’t need any sql query, but I quickly find out I couldn’t use it as it gets full pretty soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only like to highlight one sentence from your question:

> so for each element I need to make a query and get the product data from the database.

That is your problem. You do not need to do that. You can query your database with a single query and ask for all products that are in a list of IDs.

A helpful part of the SQL language is the `IN(....)` clause.

```
$ids = [123, 884, 7848, 2882, 3232]; // let's say that is your input
$idList = implode(',', array_map('intval', $ids));
$sql = sprintf(
    "SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM products WHERE products.ID IN(%s)",
    $idList
);
```

This is a single query for a list of product IDs. When you fetch the data from the data-base you create a in-memory-database on the fly (aka *Hashtable*) so that you can "fetch" data based on ID:

```
foreach($ids as $id)
{
    $concreteProduct = $rows[$id];
    ...
}
```

You also know it as `array`, just keyed by the ID value returned from the database. As the ID is unique, this just works<sup>tm</sup>.

Hope this is helpful. Some might it call premature optimization, however, you should be aware of the concept, because this can be used in many cases.